# NSArray arrayWithObjects and undefined variables

Tags: ios, objective-c

So let's say I'm trying to piece together someone's name, I have my variables:

```
@synthesize firstName = _firstName;
@synthesize middleName = _middleName;
@synthesize lastName = _lastName;
```

And I had a method where I wish to join these variables with a space in the middle, so I use:

```
NSArray *fullName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_firstName, _middleName, _lastName, nil];
self.fullName = [fullName componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

However, if `_firstName` is `undefined`, or `nil`, then the rest of the variables don't get added to my `fullName` array. What's another way around this?

The problem I want to solve is finding an efficient way of adding joining multiple strings together in a manner that'll avoid having extra whitespace.

Comment: first check then combine. if(firstname==nil)firstname=@"";

Comment: @user2864740: `arrayWithObjects:count:` and the NSArray literal throw a runtime exception if any of the objects is `nil`.

Comment: @MartinR Ugly, didn't realize that :(

Comment: What would you like to happen if you don't have information on someones name?

Comment: So if I don't have the `firstName` and `middleName` but I have the `lastName`, then I'd like `fullName` to just be the `lastName`, for eg.

Comment: You're not making clear what problem you _really_ want to solve.

Comment: I've updated the post to outline the problem that I _really_ want to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took some inspiration from @GregP and @ansible and wrote this:

First I assigned empty strings to each variable

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];

    _firstName = @"";
    _middleName = @"";
    _lastName = @"";

    return self;
}
```

Then in my method I ran them through a loop:

```
-(void)updateFullName {
    NSMutableArray *fullName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *names = @[_firstName, _middleName, _lastName];

    for (NSString *name in names) {
        if ([name length]) {
            [fullName addObject:name];
        }
    }

    self.fullName = [fullName componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
}
```

This meant that I can deal with a larger number of variables and also get around the problem of extra whitespace in the `self.fullName` final value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do. When you initialize your names before they get loaded in set them to a blank string @"". This way they are never nil just empty.

Edit: You then could use the function below to build them together

```
- (NSString *)fullName:(NSArray *)names
{
    NSInteger c = 0;
    NSString *fullName = @"";
    for (NSString *name in names)
    {
        if ([name length] > 0)
        {
            if (c != 0)
            {
                fullName = [fullName stringByAppendingString:@" "];
            }
            fullName = [fullName stringByAppendingString:name];
            c++;
        }
    }
    return fullName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use variable argument list. The downside is you either need to use a null terminal list (which is basically what `arrayWithObjects:` is) or specify or how many arguments you have.

See - http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html.

It would look something like this

```
-(NSMutableArray *) arrayWithNumber:(int) num withValues:(NSString *)firstArg,...
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstArg);
    NSString *arg = firstArg;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        // We have the first argument from va_start, so only grab the additional ones
        if (i > 0)
            arg = va_arg(args, NSString*);

        if (arg!= nil)
        {
            [array addObject:arg];
        }
    }

    return array;
}

-(void) testMethod
{
    NSString *first = @"First";
    NSString *second = nil;
    NSString *third = @"Third";

    NSMutableArray *a = [self arrayWithNumber:3 withValues:first,second,third];
    NSLog(@"%@",a);
}
```

Of course for you situation this is probably overkill but thought I would throw it out there as a possibility if you are dealing with something different then what you shown.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (using literals):

```
NSArray *fullName= @[(_firstName ? _firstName : [NSNull null]), 
    (_middleName ? _middleName : [NSNull null]),
    (_lastName ? _lastName : [NSNull null])
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a loop or check all the strings before appending to the result and avoid using **componentsJoinedByString**, but if you really want to use it then this code works:

```
NSString *firstName = @"First";
NSString *middleName = nil;
NSString *lastName = @"Last";

NSMutableArray *fullNameArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[firstName ?: [NSNull null], middleName ?: [NSNull null], lastName ?: [NSNull null]]];
[fullNameArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]];

NSString *fullName = [fullNameArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

NSLog(@"Full Name: '%@'", fullName);
```

And the result is:

```
Full Name: 'First Last'
```

Answer (score -1):

You could ensure that `_firstName`, `_middleName`, and `_lastName` are not nil by initializing them with an empty value. Potentially in `viewDidLoad` you could do the following:

```
_firstName = [NSString string];
_middleName = [NSString string];
_lastName = [NSString string];
```

Comment: No, because then he will get extra blanks in his answer.

Comment: The question was how to avoid the `NSArray` from ignoring the rest of his values, not how to format the strings should they be empty.

Answer (score -1):

Try use an `if` statement?

```
if (_firstName && _middleName && _lastName){
    NSArray *fullName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_firstName, _middleName, _lastName, nil];
    self.fullName = [fullName componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
} else {
    //Behaviour you want if there is some missing. 
}
```

Comment: No, because then if there is no first name he won't get any answer at all.

Comment: @matt, that wasn't the OP's question. You're inferring that this is a state they don't want.